# How to avoid using view to join two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have query that is currently using views. I'm trying to find a way to avoid views since they are slow and they bring more columns that I need. Here is example of the query that I would like to simplify:

```
SELECT T3.prod_type_id AS type_id
FROM store_profile T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vw_type T3 -- Get latest record from this table.
        ON T1.rec_id = T3.rec_id
        AND T1.year_id = T3.year_id
```

and here is example of view `vw_type`:

```
SELECT T1.rec_id, T1.year_id, T1.prod_type_id, T1.seq_nbr
FROM type_history T1
     JOIN ( 
           SELECT rec_id, year_id, MAX(seq_nbr) AS seq_nbr
           FROM type_history 
           GROUP BY rec_id, year_id
     ) T2
           ON T1.rec_id = T2.rec_id
           AND T1.year_id = T2.year_id
           AND T1.seq_nbr = T2.seq_nbr
```

I'm wondering how to get same results but instead of having view try to join two tables directly. If anyone have suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way of doing it

```
SELECT T1.*, T3.prod_type_id AS type_id 
FROM   store_profile T1 
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 prod_type_id 
                    FROM   type_history T2 
                    WHERE  T1.rec_id = T2.rec_id 
                           AND T1.year_id = T2.year_id 
                    ORDER  BY seq_nbr DESC) t3
```

if your rdbms doesn't support `Apply` operator, then move it to `correlated sub-query`.

Answer (score 0):

You can below way -

```
    SELECT T3.prod_type_id AS type_id
    FROM store_profile T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
    select * from
    (
      SELECT T1.rec_id, T1.year_id, T1.prod_type_id, T1.seq_nbr
      FROM type_history T1
      JOIN ( 
           SELECT rec_id, year_id, MAX(seq_nbr) AS seq_nbr
           FROM type_history 
           GROUP BY rec_id, year_id
           ) T2
           ON T1.rec_id = T2.rec_id AND T1.year_id = T2.year_id
              AND T1.seq_nbr = T2.seq_nbr
    )T3 on  ON T1.rec_id = T3.rec_id AND T1.year_id = T3.year_id
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that without partition by? I'm asking since this query should work in `Sybase` database as well. Thank you.